# How to transmit data from 1 form to another in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, connection

I want to access the openConnection from my dbconnect class from by other form but it does not work properly. I have to copy-paste the entire Oopenconnection to the other page for them to access it.

class dbconnect

```
class DB_Connect
{
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;

    //Constructor
    public DB_Connect()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    //Initialize values
    private void Initialize()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "xyz";
        uid = "root";
        password = "";

        string connectionString = $"datasource=127.0.0.1;port = 3306; SERVER={server}; DATABASE={database}; USERNAME={uid}; PASSWORD={password};sslmode=none";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    //open connection to database
    public bool OpenConnection()
    {

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {

            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server. Contact administrator");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

    //Close connection
    public bool CloseConnection()
    {
         try
            {
                connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
         }

    }

}
```

MyForm 2
On click data is being displayed on dataGridView

```
 private void display_record_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DB_Connect connect = new DB_Connect(); // I believe this part does not work

        string show_query = "SELECT * FROM testing_tb"; 

        if (connect.OpenConnection() == true)
        {

            using (MySqlCommand cmd_DB = new MySqlCommand(show_query, connection))
            {

                try
                {

                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd_DB.ExecuteReader())

                        if (reader.HasRows)

                        {

                            dt = new DataTable();
                            dt.Load(reader);
                            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("No data record detected");
                        }

                    connect.CloseConnection();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)

                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to database!\n" + ex, "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }// end of catch

            } // end of MySQLCommand

        } // end of connection check
    }
```

I want to access data from my `dtconnect class` so that I do not have to paste `public bool OpenConnection(){}` in every new form that I want to open connection.

**Error:** could not connect to database, connection must be valid and open, etc..

Comment: Your DBConnect class doesnt return or expose a MySQL connection object.  It is a bad idea.  Connection pooling means you should create, use and dispose of connections where you need them

Comment: what the proper way to do it then, do u have an example?

Comment: I already told you: *you should create, use and dispose of connections where you need them*.  Make the connection string a module level variable so it doesnt have to repeat.  It is all well documented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want the connection available everywhere you can use this:

```
public static class Connection
{
    private const string ConnectionString = "YOUR CONNECTION";
    public static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Conn { get; private set; } = null;

    public static void Open()
    {
        try
        {
            Conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            Conn.Open();
        }
        catch { System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Can't connect to the server, please check if you have an internet connection."); }
    }

    public static void Close() { Conn.Close(); }
}
```

It is not recommended because your connection will be open at all time so you should do this instead:

```
    public static class Connection
{
    private const string ConnectionString = "YOUR CONNECTION";
    public static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Conn { get; private set; } = null;

    public static void Create() { Conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString); }
    public static void Open()
    {
        try { Conn.Open(); }
        catch { System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Can't connect to the server, please check if you have an internet connection."); }
    }

    public static void Close() { Conn.Close(); }
}
```

And you open and close your connection when needed.
So basically, when you open your connection when using a query you use `Connection.Open()` and `Connection.Close()`. It is now accessible from everywhere if the class is in the using of your forms.

Here's a link about the connection state: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142065/creating-database-connections-do-it-once-or-for-each-query